# Java EE get IP through proxy

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets

Is there any way to get someones IP if that person is using "ultrasurf" or any other program?

I got this code so far:

```
String ip = request.getHeader("X-Forwarded-For");
    if (ip == null || ip.length() == 0 || "unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ip)) {
        ip = request.getHeader("Proxy-Client-IP");
    }
  if (ip == null || ip.length() == 0 || "unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ip)) {
        ip = request.getHeader("WL-Proxy-Client-IP");
    }
 if (ip == null || ip.length() == 0 || "unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ip)) {
        ip = request.getHeader("HTTP_CLIENT_IP");
    }
 if (ip == null || ip.length() == 0 || "unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ip)) {
        ip = request.getHeader("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR");
    }
if (ip == null || ip.length() == 0 || "unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ip)) {
        ip = request.getRemoteAddr();
    }
```

Am I missing some Header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible to get the origin IP.

Neither for users hiding behind an anonymize network, company proxy or a simple router at home.